# Program to draw ASCII trees

Tags: graphs, ascii

I'm looking for a program that can draw ASCII trees and:

- has a GUI
- add/remove/move child/parent nodes
- easily rename node
- add labels on the edges
- automatically place new nodes (i.e. I don't want to draw the edges manually)

Bonus point if:

- is free
- works on Windows 7

Example:

> ```
>                   Sentence
>                      |
>        +-------------+------------+
>        |                          |
>   Noun Phrase                Verb Phrase
>        |                          |
>      John                 +-------+--------+
>                           |                |
>                         Verb          Noun Phrase
>                           |                |
>                         sees              Bill
> ```

With labels on the edges:

> ```
>               sees
>                 |
>         +--------------+
> subject |              | object
>         |              |
>       John            Bill
> ```

E.g. http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw is not good as we cannot easily move a node.

Comment: I've found [a Prolog program](http://www.nyu.edu/pages/linguistics/workbook/lehner/) which supposedly does this, but it throws an exception when I give it the sample data on the website. If you know how to make it work, please let me know; I'm also very interested in finding a program like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [Monodraw](https://monodraw.helftone.com/).

It has a **line tool** and comes with the explicit ability to draw ER Diagrams, Mind Maps and diagrams in general.

But it won't fulfill your bonus points as it works on MacOS only and is not free (one license is $9.99). Though it gives a free trial.