# Software to draw shapes in plain text file (ASCII/Unicode)

Tags: windows, text-editor, drawing, plain-text, ascii

Sometimes I need to draw simple shapes into plain text documentation file. What application can do this? Last time I've used such an app under MS-DOS :) (It was called **Flow** or something like that.)

Using standard ASCII characters:

```
--------------          --------------
|   Source   |--------->|   Source   |
|   File 1   |<---------|   File 2   |
--------------          --------------
```

Possibly also using good old table-drawing characters brought back to life by Unicode:

```
╔═══════════╤═══╗     ┌─────────┐
║ Semaphore │ A ║     │ Queue   │
╚═══════════╧═══╝     └─────────┘
```

I need this for Windows.

Comment: Similar question, but with no answer http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/program-to-draw-ascii-trees

Comment: @Cornelius – yup, thanks for linking. This one should be for general drawing.

Comment: To all: I'll mark the answer later, once I try solutions you proposed.

Answer (score 7):

Try **TorchSoft [ASCII Art Studio](http://www.torchsoft.com/en/aas_information.html)**

- works on Windows
- supports shapes, tables
- text mode for easy editing
- freehand drawing
- conversion from picture to ASCII
- it has a 30 day trial
- single user license is 29.95 $

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/):

- proprietary, free of charge
- online
- can upload files to Google Drive
- basic shapes:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use  [JavE](http://www.jave.de/):

- closed source freeware
- Cross-platform (Java) (`java -jar jave5.jar`)

[image]

Also it contains a pretty nice math formula editor:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[FAR Manager](http://farmanager.com/) has an internal editor with "Draw Lines" capability (Press `F11`, then select "Draw lines"). May be enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

What you show in your example looks a lot like UML.

If sequence diagrams are what you need, here's a tool that does both ASCII and Unicode

PlantUML, Open Source

http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/ascii_art.html

Comment: Although to produce diagrams using this tool, declarations are required based on which diagrams are drawn, proposed tool looks quite valuable for special-purpose charting – thank you.

Comment: Up 1 if you like it ;-)

Comment: – it is good your answer is here to show potentially useful UML tool, it might find its use in special cases. But for standard ASCII-drawing (as I expected in my question) it looks to be too difficult. I think I can't achieve shapes shown in the question without studying the tool's language first. This is why I decided not to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The [ADia](https://github.com/pylover/adia) project aims to render ASCII diagrams using a human-readable language:

```
diagram: Foo
sequence:
foo -> bar: Hello World!
```

Output

```
 DIAGRAM: Foo                             

 +-----+             +-----+
 | foo |             | bar |
 +-----+             +-----+
    |                   |
    |~~~Hello World!~~~>|
    |                   |
    |<------------------|
    |                   |
 +-----+             +-----+
 | foo |             | bar |
 +-----+             +-----+
```

Read the [documentation](https://pylover.github.io/adia/docs/latest/html/) or  Try the [live demo](https://pylover.github.io/adia/) page at `github.io`.