# Visual scripting alternatives but for text ( text node editor )?

Tags: text-editor, text-processing, scripting

I want to create tech document for my friend, and want to provide some logic structure. Is there any Visual Scripting alternatives but for text editing? Something like visual pseudo-scritping. Where I can create infinite blocks with text and connect each other with arrows/lines ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software to draw shapes in plain text file (ASCII/Unicode)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3916/3579), [Program to draw ASCII trees](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2349/3579), [Create ASCII art tables](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/43498/3579)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software to draw shapes in plain text file (ASCII/Unicode)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/software-to-draw-shapes-in-plain-text-file-ascii-unicode)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the drawing of preudo-graphic lines in the text file, I recommend [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor, with its [plugin "Draw Lines"](https://github.com/CudaText-addons/cuda_draw_lines/blob/master/readme/readme.txt). Install Draw Lines in menu `Plugins / Addon Manager / Install`. Then call this plugin from `Plugins / Draw Lines`.

I painted small block set for you:

```
                   ┌──────────────────┐
                   │    main block    │
                   │      title       │
                   └─────┬────┬───────┘
                         │    │
               ┌─────────┘    └────┐
               │                   │
     ┌─────────┴──────┐            │     ╔═════════════════╗
     │  first block   │            │     ║  second block   ║
     ├────────────────┤            └─────╬═════════════════╣
     │     title1     │                  ║  title          ║
     └────────────────┘                  ║      again...   ║
                                         ╚═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Looks good (+1), but I suspect that the OP wants to describe the boxes, their text & relationships & have the layout down automagically @oysho ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my answer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/software-to-draw-the-data-flow-of-a-program/19313#19313).

In fact, I have given the same answer to [many questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3397+graphviz).

I think that [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is the tool for you. Describe the boxes, with their text & relationship (work flow) between them & GraphViz will automagically lay the diagram out for you.

This input:

```
graph {  
           a -- b;   
           b -- c;   
           a -- c;   
           d -- c;   
           e -- c;   
           e -- a;   
      }
```

draws this output:

[image]

Obviously, it can produce [much more complex diagrams](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) that that, but that shows the principle - a simple text language to describe the relationship between nodes.

GraphViz has been around for a long time, is well supported, has an [active forum](http://www.graphviz.org/forum) and is widely used in academia and in some popular tools like DoxyGen.